# Java procedural 2d terrain low-poly style

Tags: java, android, 2d, procedural-generation

I'am working on a game with an low poly style. I have been searching for precedural terrain generation but there where only 3d or tile based tutorials.

**INFO:**

- Langue is Java using the libGDX framework and released on android.
- The terrain will be generated procedural while the game is running using a chunk loading system (for an infinite world).
- The game terrain will be saved. And should be reloaded with the same terrain.
- The Terrain can be convex (caves).

[image: terrain]

**QUESTION:**

- Are there any good tutorials or libs?
- If I use chunks to only load parts of the map some triangles vertices will contain 2 differen chunks how to manage these?
- I have read that I shouldn't save / load a chunk to a file. But just generate the terrain using a seed. How do I tell the generator to not generate something that was removed previously?
- What about entities save them to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A few bits of general advice I have

- Possible vertex overlap could be accounted for by defining and saving chunks with *padding* to account for the maximum a vertex could go outside of its chunk. Minecraft, for example, never had this problem because cubes line up very nicely. You could consider changing the geometry you're using. For example: define the world as cubes, and then apply an effect to move all vertices pseudo-randomly and thus hide that you're generating using cubes.
- I would generate all terrain using a seed instead of saving and
  loading from a file *except* for in chunks where something has been
  removed. Those chunks *will* need to be saved. You could overwrite seed chunks with these.
- Just like you said in your question, handle entities by: saving them to a .properties file or something. I would using a `LinkedList<>` or `array[]` with an abstract parent class to keep track of them in-game.

### Some videos about procedural generation in general:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdYkcrW8FBg
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ORcSjvESrA

This is all pretty abstract information, but I didn't want to leave this without any response. Hopefully someone with more experience in the particular area can give you more practical insight.